# How to handle Exception within other try catch block?

Tags: php, oop

My example:

```
class CustomException extends \Exception {

}

class FirstClass {
    function method() {
        try {
            $get = external();
            if (!isset($get['ok'])) {
                throw new CustomException;
            }

            return $get;
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo 'ERROR1'; die();
        }
    }
}

class SecondClass {
    function get() {
        try {
            $firstClass = new FirstClass();
            $get = $firstClass->method();
        } catch (CustomException $e) {
            echo 'ERROR2'; die();
        }
    }
}

$secondClass = new SecondClass();
$secondClass->get();
```

This return me "ERROR1", but I would like receive "ERROR2" from SecondClass.

In FirstClass block try catch should handle errors from external() method.

How can I make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of printing an error message and die the whole php process, you should rather throw another exception and register an global exception handler, which does the exception handling for unhandled exceptions.

```
class CustomException extends \Exception {

}

class FirstClass {
    function method() {
        try {
            $get = external();
            if (!isset($get['ok'])) {
                throw new CustomException;
            }

            return $get;
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            // maybe do some cleanups..
            throw $ex;
        }
    }
}

class SecondClass {
    function get() {
        try {
            $firstClass = new FirstClass();
            $get = $firstClass->method();
        } catch (CustomException $e) {
            // some other cleanups
            throw $e;
        }
    }
}

$secondClass = new SecondClass();
$secondClass->get();
```

You could register an global exception handler with `set_exception_handler`

```
set_exception_handler(function ($exception) {
    echo "Uncaught exception: " , $exception->getMessage(), "\n";
});
```